# MySQL - Getting data for week ahead

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT
    "bookings"."customerID",
    "bookings"."arrivalDate",
    "bookings"."leavingDate",
    "bookings"."bookingID",
    "bookings"."pickup",
    "bookings"."dropoff",
    "bookings"."locationID",
    "locations"."locationName",
    "customers"."customerName"
FROM
    "bookings"
LEFT JOIN "customers" ON
    "bookings"."customerID" = "customers"."customerID"
LEFT JOIN "locations" ON
    "bookings"."locationID" = "locations"."locationID"
WHERE (
    "bookings"."arrivalDate" BETWEEN '2014-11-15' AND '2014-11-22'
)
```

What i'm hoping to get is all the bookings for the week ahead. Sorted by oldest first. Just cant get it to work!

Comment: plz remove the double code and try again.

Comment: Double code? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: _just cant get it to work_: what error do you get? what is your expected result?

Comment: Hi, It just returns nothing when I know there should be information.

Comment: Try removing all the double quotes -- MySql uses backticks.

Comment: Thats not the issue. :) Thats something I fixed.

Comment: Do you get results when leaving away the WHERE clause?

Comment: so what's the issue? May i know the error msg?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      b.customerID,
      b.arrivalDate,
      b.leavingDate,
      b.bookingID,
      b.pickup,
      b.dropoff,
      b.locationID,
      l.locationName,
      c.customerName
   FROM
      bookings b
         LEFT JOIN customers c
            ON b.customerID = c.customerID
         LEFT JOIN locations l
            ON b.locationID = l.locationID
   WHERE 
      b.arrivalDate > curdate()
      AND b.arrivalDate <= date_add( curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
   order by 
      b.leavingDate DESC
```

I updated to utilize aliases vs long table name references.  Also, the where clause to make use of the current date and 7 days forward to get the week ahead so it is not hard-referenced.  You could additionally adjust in case you wanted the query always to be based on a Sat or Sun of a given week.

As for the sorting by the "oldest" first... oldest in what way... just change the order by clause.  I am GUESSING your intent was on the date leaving out... So by that column DESCENDING would put the oldest LEAVING item at the top of the list.